# Is there a possibility in CMake don't scan for specific folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm using the CMake Tools Extension in Visual Studio Code.

In my WorspaceSettings.code file I have set two paths. Path A is the path where my CMakeLists.txt file is located. Path B is another path with source files, I need for the project set in path A. Every time I configure the cmake project I get the message, that cmake didn't found a CMakeLists.txt file in the root folder (logically, because there is none). When I build all projects I get again the mentioned message of the missing CMakeLists.txt file.

Is there a possibility CMake only scan path A and path B CMake shall ignore, so I don't get the messages from VS Code?
Or is there a general possibility to prevent this message?

Comment: Can you just change your root folder to Path A? Then, use the CMake file to include the files in Path B...

Comment: I have the needed sources included to the CMakeLists.txt file. This works fine. But, when I remove Path B from the WorkspaceSettings.code file, then I don't see the files in the Explorer Pane of VS Code. Either I can see the sources in the Explorer pane, when Path B is in Workspace file and I get the CMake warning or vice versa.